# Why Unknown Characters appear in my ADF XML?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, string

I am working on an ADF file format (XML used by lead management).

The XML is generated dynamically in rails and sent as part of the email. The dynamic string is:

```
<xml><?ADF VERSION '1.0'?><?XML VERSION '1.0'?>
    <adf>
        <prospect>
            <requestdate>#{inquiry.created_at}</requestdate>
            <vehicle interest='buy'></vehicle>
            <customer>
                <contact>
                    <comments>Subject: #{inquiry.subject if inquiry.subject}, Comment: #{inquiry.comment if inquiry.comment}</comments>
                    <name part='first'>#{inquiry.first_name if inquiry.first_name}</name><name part='last'>#{inquiry.last_name if inquiry.last_name}</name>
                    <email>#{inquiry.from_email if inquiry.from_email }</email>
                    <phone>#{inquiry.phone if inquiry.phone}</phone>
                </contact>
            </customer>

            <vendor>
             <contact><email>#{inquiry.to_email if inquiry.to_email}</email></contact>
             <contact><email>#{user.leademail1 if user.leademail1 }</email></contact>
             <contact><email>#{user.leademail2 if user.leademail2 }</email></contact>
            </vendor>
        </prospect>
    </adf>
</xml>
```

This XML is passed as string as shown below which is used by a function which take the content and sends the email:

```
"<html><head><style type='text/css'>body,html,.body{background:#e8e1e1!important;}</style></head><body><container><spacer size='16'></spacer><row><columns large='8'><center><h2>New Lead From Want A Car Buy A Car</h2></center></columns></row><row><columns large='6'><left><h4>**Please reply back to the customer using contact information below. **</h4><br><p><strong>Contact:</strong></p><p>Subject: #{inquiry.subject if inquiry.subject}</p><p>First Name: #{inquiry.first_name if inquiry.first_name}</p><p>Last Name: #{inquiry.last_name if inquiry.last_name}</p><p>Email: #{inquiry.from_email if inquiry.from_email }</p><p>Telephone: #{inquiry.phone if inquiry.phone}</p><br><p>Comments: #{inquiry.comment if inquiry.comment}</p><br> </left></columns><columns large='6'><left><p>**Want even more exposure on <a href = 'http://www.wantacarbuyacar.com'>Want A Car Buy A Car</a>? Try our premium display options. Call us at +1 866-338-7870 Line 5 or email us for more info. **</p></left></columns><columns large='6'><left><p>**Check out <a href = 'http://the-dealers-choice.com/'>The Dealers Choice</a> for more programs**</p></center></left><columns large='6'><center><p>For assistance, contact us at: Phone: +1 866-338-7870 Line 5, Email:sales@tdcdigitalmedia.com</p></center></columns><columns large='6'><center><p><a href = 'http://www.wantacarbuyacar.com'>Want A Car Buy A Car</a></p></center></columns><columns large='4'><center><img class='small-float-center' width='100px' height='100px' src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/wacbacassetsdonttouch/wacbacassets/THEDEALERSCHOICElogosmall3.png' alt=''></center></columns></row></container><body></html><xml><?ADF VERSION '1.0'?><?XML VERSION “1.0”?><adf><prospect><requestdate>#{inquiry.created_at}</requestdate><vehicle interest='buy'></vehicle><customer><contact><comments>Subject: #{inquiry.subject if inquiry.subject}, Comment: #{inquiry.comment if inquiry.comment}</comments><name part='first'>#{inquiry.first_name if inquiry.first_name}</name><name part='last'>#{inquiry.last_name if inquiry.last_name}</name><email>#{inquiry.from_email if inquiry.from_email }</email><phone>#{inquiry.phone if inquiry.phone}</phone></contact></customer><vendor><contact><email>#{inquiry.to_email if inquiry.to_email}</email></contact><contact><email>#{user.leademail1 if user.leademail1 }</email></contact><contact><email>#{user.leademail2 if user.leademail2 }</email></contact></vendor></prospect></adf></xml>"
```

The problem is when an analyzer is analyzing the lead through the email received, the email has extra characters as shown below(received picture from the DMS client):[image]

How can I make sure these extra characters don't show up in the final XML? Is it an encoding problem?

Comment: Check the apostrophes around `1.0`. It should be plain apostrophe character (ASCII 39), not some "single quote" characters. What are you using to write your code? Use some editor suitable for programming.

Comment: @MladenJablanović thanks. I changed it. what about the name part. I am using ' ' but its adding a 3D in front. Also the = after <adf>=

Comment: You have [quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding somewhere in your pipeline. I advise inspecting the content at every point in your pipeline and that will help you identify the place where the superfluous encoding is being performed.

Comment: Ah now I noticed that you are sending the XML as email. Well, your email client is QP-encoding your XML before sending, but your receiving end does not decode it for some reason. So, I'd guess email is the problem.